# How to get the JobID from Deadline using a Python script

Tags: python, maya, sched-deadline

Is there any way to get the Job Id from Deadline. I am scripting the process of submitting a job from Maya to Deadline without using the GUI. I need the JobId in order to create a folder in the repository to save the Maya Scene File when submitted. 
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about scripting Maya or Deadline but you might consider providing more details and/or posting some code. I think it's a perfectly valid question but it usually helps to show some effort.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting via `deadlinecommand.exe`, it has an output that contains all the job IDs. The lines can be split by `\r\n`, and every line containing an ID will start with `JobID=`.

Here's an example output from submitting two jobs at the same time:

```
Deadline Command 9.0 [v9.0.8.4 Release]

Submitting to Repository: \\<company server>\repo

Submission Contains No Auxiliary Files.

Result=Success
JobID=5beebe64afcefe068846e319

The job was submitted successfully, but there were some warnings:
- Invalid characters removed from "LimitGroups" value.


Deadline Command 9.0 [v9.0.8.4 Release]

Submitting to Repository: \\<company server>\repo

Submission Contains No Auxiliary Files.

Result=Success
JobID=5beebe65afcefe068846e31c

The job was submitted successfully, but there were some warnings:
- Invalid characters removed from "LimitGroups" value.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Peter